# git push >> fatal: no configured push destination

Tags: git, github, push, git-push

I'm still going through some guides on RoR and I'm stuck here at [Deploying The Demo App](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/a-demo-app#sec:2.3.5)

I followed instructions:

> With the completion of the Microposts resource, now is a good time to push the repository up to GitHub:
>
> ```
> $ git add .
> $ git commit -a -m "Done with the demo app"
> $ git push
> ```

What happened wrong here was the push part.. it outputted this:

```
$ git push
fatal: No configured push destination.
Either specify the URL from the command-line or configure a remote repository using
git remote add <name> <url>
git push <name>
```

So I tried following the instructions by doing this command:

```
$ git remote add demo_app 'www.github.com/levelone/demo_app'
fatal: remote demo_app already exists.
```

So I push:

```
$ git push demo_app
fatal: 'www.github.com/levelone/demo_app' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

What can I do here? Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Very good question. Most tutorials seem to be missing one or two steps, making it impossible to push your changes.

Comment: I got the same error and then I found out that it was directory-related issue. I was not pushing from the right directory where the repo is settled.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

The command (or the URL in it) to add the github repository as a remote isn't quite correct. If I understand your repository name correctly, it should be;

```
git remote add demo_app 'git@github.com:levelone/demo_app.git'
```

Comment: After doing this I keep having following error: `git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey)`

Comment: That's because it's a private repository

Answer (score 59):

You are referring to the section "[2.3.5 Deploying the demo app](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/a-demo-app#sec:2.3.5)" of this "[Ruby on Rails Tutorial](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/a-demo-app) ":

In section [2.3.1 Planning the application](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/a-demo-app#sec:planning_the_application), note that they did:

```
$ git remote add origin git@github.com:<username>/demo_app.git
$ git push -u origin master
```

That is why a simple `git push` worked (using here an ssh address).
Did you follow that step and made that first push?

```
 www.github.com/levelone/demo_app
```

That would not be a writable URI for pushing to a GitHub repo.

```
https://levelone@github.com/levelone/demo_app.git
```

This should be more appropriate.
Check what `git remote -v` returns, and if you need to replace the remote address, as described in [GitHub help page](http://help.github.com/remotes/), use `git remote --set-url`.

```
git remote set-url origin https://levelone@github.com/levelone/demo_app.git
# or 
git remote set-url origin git@github.com:levelone/demo_app.git
```

Comment: It works! @VonC but unfortunately I'm stuck right after I push once again... 
After using: `git push demo_app` it outputs a Password Authentication, and after successfully logging in it displays: 
`No refs in common and none specified; doing nothing;
perhaps you should specify a branch such as 'master'.
Everything-up-to-date`

i don't get it..

Comment: @Marc if it asks for a password, then you must have missed a configuration allowing you to authenticate to GitHub as the rightful owner of demo_app. See for instance (with an https remote GitHub address) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7129232/problem-in-pushing-to-github/7130405#7130405 or (more complete) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5377703/syncing-with-github/5378094#5378094

Comment: the first link didn't change the output of my push.. i'm curious on how to set my < login_internet >, < password_internet >, @ aproxy, aport ... i'm kinda lost :( sorry about that. hope i'm not bugging you for your help..

Comment: @Marc: you only need to setup that if you do access internet through a proxy.

Comment: oh ok.. i access the net through our wifi here at home. i hope that helps? so yea when i push `$ git push` it displays this text `error: error setting certificate verify locations:  CA file: \bin\curl-ca-bundle.crt   CApath: none    while accessing https:\\levelone@github.com/levelone/demo_app.git/info/refs  fatal:HTTPS request failed` do i need my rails server on while i push it? or i do have to set up my proxy?

Comment: and i tried cloning it.. and destination path 'demo app' already exists and is not an empty directory.

Comment: @Marc check your global git config to set the CA file path appropriately: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3778244/6309. And when you clone, always do it by specifying a root directory which doesn't exist yet.

Comment: I am on bitbucket when I am doing this 
git remote add abc-blog 'git@bitbucket.org:sooraz/abc-blog.git'

I am getting fatal: remote abc-blog already exists and then can't push it...

Comment: @Suraj that should be a separate question in its own, not a comment burried under a three-years old answer.

Comment: Sorry about that.. I saw your last active was just 10 minutes back and hence the comment.

Comment: @Suraj sure, I am *always* there (http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/122976/anyone-with-a-visited-2048-days-2048-consecutive-in-his-her-profile), but your question deserves more visibility: make one, for others (than just me) to answer to.

Answer (score 6):

I have faced this error, Previous I had push in root directory, and now I have push another directory, so I could be remove this error and run below commands.

```
git add .
git commit -m "some comments"
git push --set-upstream origin master
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using git commands using cmd

```
git remote add origin git@github.com:<username>/demo_app.git
```

You can copy it from your repo https code you are currently working on.

After this run

```
git push
```

This worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I already have faced this error. I create a github repository and I copy repository Url and I run following command.

```
git remote add service-center-app 'https://github.com/DeveloperAsela/service-centerapp.git'
```

Comment: This is exactly what the already `accepted answer` says.

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me when I was using Visual Studio Code with Github. I have realized that the upstream branch was empty for some reason and push did not know where to push. Using "sync" fixed the problem.

Comment: What is "sync"?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem

using vs code if you click on the menu button go down to push,pull then scroll down to push to and

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I resolve the same issue:

1. create repository
2. git branch -M main
3. git push -u origin main

Answer (score 0):

Through VS-Code:

1. git add .
2. git commit -m "some comments"
3. git remote add origin git@github.com:yourusername/yourrepository.git
4. git push --set-upstream origin master

Answer (score 0):

**This problem occurs simply because we have not set whether this repository should be private or public
to resolve this :**

- git add .
- git commit -m "your message"
- git push
- (go to git-branch icon on vscode side panel > click on publish branch
  blue botton > drop down will be open on top > select private of
  public )

**And done.**