# How to upload git folder(java application) to openshift

Tags: git, openshift

I'm following this tutorial :
https://developers.openshift.com/en/tomcat-getting-started.html#step2

Notice on step one the following part was exclude in command prompt.
Any idea why ?

```
Cloned to:  /home/me/git_demo/mytomcatapp
```

So i fixed this by following
Creating a local folder and init git there and clone the web application to there.

But now i want to upload my local web application .

I get the same proplem as [git push >> fatal: no configured push destination](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10032964/git-push-fatal-no-configured-push-destination)

But when i try :

```
git remote add demo_app 'git@github.com:levelone/demo_app.git'
```

i get an push default is unset error

I am cleary doing something wrong but i can figure out what ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You *might* have more that one push default or none set at all. You can see all the remotes for your repo by typing: `git remote -v`. If you want to push to a specific remote, just do:

`git push demo_app branch_name`

where `demo_app` is the name of your remote and `branch_name` is the name of the branch you want to push.