# r studio fatal: No configured push destination

Tags: r, git, rstudio, blogdown

I'm trying to create a blog using R package blogdown. 
The last step is to push my files to Github, and I clicked "Push Branch", 
which gave me this error message:

[image]

I'm not very experienced with Git/Github integration with R Studio. Can somebody leave a detailed explanation of what to do?

Comment: You need to setup a remote repository.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [git push >> fatal: no configured push destination](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10032964/git-push-fatal-no-configured-push-destination)

Answer (score 0):

**Syntax**

You add remote git server URL to local git repository config like this

```
git remote add origin your_git_repository_url
```

**Example**

At git local repository folder, release command:

```
git remote add origin https://github.com/donhuvy/java9.git
```

**Learn more**

https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Working-with-Remotes#_adding_remote_repositories (official reference document)

https://help.github.com/articles/adding-a-remote/

Comment: You use, https://github.com/donhuvy/java9.git                                              which url should I use?

Comment: In your case, repository stand in "local server". Read section  **Directions for Git (local)** in document: https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/200532077-Version-Control-with-Git-and-SVN