# TFS, windows authentication and commandline git (msysgit)

Tags: git, tfs

I'm trying to clone GIT repository being hosted by a corporate TFS server.

I'm able to clone this repository using VS2013. But when coming to command-line git `git version 1.9.4.msysgit.2`, git.exe fails with an `Authentication failed for 'uri'`.

On my first tries, I gave my domain credentials. With several case combinations (`DOMAIN\user`,  `domain\user`, and so on).

Then I found the page [Team Foundation Server 2013 Express - Can't connect to git repo via command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20170952/team-foundation-server-2013-express-cant-connect-to-git-repo-via-command-line), so I've tried with no authentication at all.

```
K:\GitRepositories>git clone http://tfs:8080/tfs/CegidTest2013/IVO_TestBuilds/_git/IntegrationTestsOverrides
Cloning into 'IntegrationTestsOverrides'...
Username for 'http://tfs:8080':
Password for 'http://tfs:8080':
fatal: Authentication failed for 'http://tfs:8080/tfs/CegidTest2013/IVO_TestBuilds/_git/IntegrationTestsOverrides/'
```

No luck.

While having a look at the network traffic, I see that the client's `NTLMSSP_NEGOTIATE` gets an `NTLMSSP_CHALLENGE` response. The client doesn't proceed further.

Could this be related to the fact that the TFS Server belongs to another domain than the user currently logged? This shouldn't be an issue.

I can't modify the configuration of the server without proof (that's a TFS production server, I'm not the admin).

Comment: Have you tried filling this http address into your explorer? I've had the same, and only after I had a windows logon message for the host server asking for my credentials was I able to connect with the git server on that host.

Comment: Yes, I have tried (explorer, iexplore, chrome). This host is recognized as belonging to the intranet zone. I am not asked to type any authentication during my session.

Comment: Can you clone this using that URL in Visual Studio?  Is there anything in your server log?

Comment: Yeah, I'm able to clone this URL in Visual Studio. Which logs should I get? (eventvwr?) I'm not the admin of this server..

Comment: I've some more details: the TFS host which I'm contacting is an NLB front-end. When I try to clone the repository addressing my request to one of the servers behind the NLB, git succeeds.
I suppose that this points us towards a defect in the NLB management...

Comment: I've no luck as well... I don't even get the request for specifying username and passoword: my TFS answers with 503 error when called from cmdline (but it works when called from VS)

Comment: In my experience this has always been a *client* issue. Some people had old git versions, some had to reinstall git client, some had an old git-credential-winstore. Try reinstalling you Git client: YMMV.

Comment: Thanks Giulio.
I've not updated my post since a while, and I have to say that using git for windows v2.4.2.windows.1 (available here: https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases) the problem has disappeared.
I have also to say that git for windows 1.9.5 worked for some users (and not for some others). The disponibility of git for windows 2.4 has definitely solved the problem.

Comment: @nilleb I had exact same problem as you got - VS2013 was fine whilst msysgit (and SourceTree which contains embedded msysgit) produced authentication error. The version you shared on the link actually works whilst I don't quite understand the difference, but the important thing is it's working now. Thank you so much!

Comment: @nilleb please post the solution as an answer and approve it. This way other people will find it easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Originally a comment to the above question*, posting here as it is **the** answer

Thanks @giulio-vian. I've not updated my post since a while, and I have to say that when I started using git for windows v2.4.2.windows.1 (available [here](http://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases)) the problem has disappeared. I have also to say that git for windows 1.9.5 worked for some users (and not for some others). The availability of Git for Windows 2.4 has definitely solved the problem.

Comment: Had the same problem when I upgraded to TFS 2017. Just updated Git to 2.11.0 and it worked fine.