# git push fails with git-credential-winstore

Tags: git, authentication, github

I have an issue that I believe is with the git-credential-winstore application.

I am trying to store credentials so that I don't have to enter them each time.

I have done this process on one computer (my personal laptop) and it works perfectly, but when I'm trying to repeat the process on a work computer it is failing.

I installed git-credential-winstore, ran it, and then attempted to push my local repo to github. On the first push, the git-credential-winstore application asks for my credentials, and after I input them it completes the push.

However, the next time I attempt to push, it doesn't ask for credentials but the push fails. I have gotten two failure messages, and I haven't identified what I do differently to get one vs. the other. I either get "remote: Anonymous access to ***/***.git denied" or I get "invalid username/password".

I've noticed that while on my laptop a new credential appeared in the windows credential manager, nothing appears on my desktop. Furthermore, if I manually enter the credential exactly as it appears on my laptop, then next time I look at the Windows Credential Manager the new credential has disappeared.

Any ideas what might be happening here? Is it possible that I don't have sufficient permissions on the desktop to add credentials and not have them be cleared away?

Thanks,

Comment: Don't bother with a cache: it is buggy on Windows. Use an encrypted file: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18362082/6309

Comment: Do you know what version you installed? I got the same problem when I installed with chocolately. It installed v1.3 which is an alpha. Installing the latest stable release (v1.2) works fine.

Comment: Note to others with this issue: it may be useful to know these commands when troubleshooting Windows Credential Store issues: `cmdkey /list` and `cmdkey /generic:LegacyGeneric:target=git:https://mysite.visualstudio.com /user:MyName /pass:MyPass123`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This was in the comments, but v1.3 of the package is buggy and almost never works.  Do a force install of v 1.2 and it will work.

If using [Chocolately](http://chocolatey.org/packages/git-credential-winstore):

```
cinst git-credential-winstore -version 1.2
```