# How can I configure bitbucket to dont allow users commit on the head and still have permissions to grab the code using sourcetree?

Tags: git, bitbucket, atlassian-sourcetree

I am struggling trying to use bitbucket and the git-flow, so, I downloaded sourcetree and seems to be very easy to use and all.

So, I created a group and imported a repository to it (just like that)

So, now when I login with another account (for testing) it says im part of that group and when I want to import a project it appears on the list of remote web projects, I start with the gitflow locally and everything works fine.

I cannot push the updates, this user have read-only access.

So, I want to create a pull request (Dont know why pull request, shouldnt be a push request) ??

And everytime I try it says Fata: Authentication failed for `https://<username>:<password>@bitbucket.org/<username>/<repo>.git`

Which I really dont understand why, its annoying...

Checked this question but I still couldnt solve it [Authentication failed to bitbucket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20953940/authentication-failed-to-bitbucket)

Any idea how to fix it? or make it work? or make the whole flow work with restricted permissions?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

add ssh-key to all of you r users and clone using ssh.

to add key:
https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/BITBUCKET/Add+an+SSH+key+to+an+account

Comment: should very user generates it? when I work with the user that creates the repo doesnt ask for any (I guess is because of that)

Comment: Every user needs to have its own key, its a pair of private+public keys. The user who creates the repository will have to add you as a team memebrs

Comment: Hi, now it throws the same error, but now it says Authentication failed for ... and shows the correct user, still, i cannot make a pull request, any idea?

Comment: Have you added the user as collaborator https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/BITBUCKET/Add+Users,+Set+Permissions,+and+Review+Account+Plans

Answer (score 0):

Well,

Basicall, you cannot make a pull request if you have read access only, you need to have write access (which makes no sense to make pull requests if you can write it directly)

I think is not nice that sourcetree and bitbucket work like that.