# ssh-askpass error from Visual Studio Code on OSX when attempting to clone a remote Git repo

Tags: macos, visual-studio-code, homebrew

Running Visual Studio Code on OSX Mojave 10.14.6

I had to install ssh-askpass via brew (see [VS Code gives me an ssh_askpass error when I try to push the changes to my Github repository using the integrated git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52885928/vs-code-gives-me-an-ssh-askpass-error-when-i-try-to-push-the-changes-to-my-githu))

But still I am getting a strange error which I don't know where to start with.

[image]