# GitLab - HTTP Basic: Access Failed

Tags: git

I haven't pushed to this repo in a few weeks, but now i can't. I ran into an issue like this before and remedied it by clearing git credentials as i saw in another StackOverflow post. However none of the questions i have found have remedied this issue.

This is a new branch that i'm setting up and trying to push, i'm also up to date on the latest Git as of 6/5/2018, and i don't have 2FA set up on this account as of right now.

Any and all help in fixing this would be greatly appreciated because i can't find a way to fix this at all through their documentation or stack overflow.

```
$ git push --set-upstream origin updateToUnity2018.1
remote: HTTP Basic: Access denied
fatal: Authentication failed for 'https://gitlab.com/buffet-time/project-top-down.git/'
```

Comment: Might this problem be similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47860772/gitlab-remote-http-basic-access-denied-and-fatal-authentication ?

Comment: As i stated, i already tried clearing git credentials to no avail.

Comment: What OS are you using. Are you behind a firewall or a proxy?

Comment: Windows 10 x64 latest update, no firewall, no proxy, no VPN

Comment: Possible duplicate of [GitLab remote: HTTP Basic: Access denied and fatal Authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47860772/gitlab-remote-http-basic-access-denied-and-fatal-authentication)

Comment: If you look at the answer i submitted to this i was pointed to a different stack overflow post than the one you posted

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After submitting a [support request on GitLab](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-com/support-forum/issues/3508#note_79607665)

I was pointed to this stackoverflow post, and this fixed my issue which ended up being GitLab for some reason not bringing up git credentials in the normal way.

[Git: Failed to erase credential: Element not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17074941/git-failed-to-erase-credential-element-not-found)

Comment: Thank you!  I've been stuck on this and trying various solutions my searching has turned up, but nothing worked.  Opening up the credential manager and deleting the Windows Credentials for the remote repository worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

I was also facing same issue
`remote: HTTP Basic: Access denied fatal: Authentication failed for 'https://:@gitlab********`

so i opened terminal and checked for cat gitconfig and removed `[url "https://:@gitlab.***"] insteadOf = https://gitlab.*****/`  and then i tried pulling or pushing it asked me username and password again, and it worked.

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

i had the same issue but this was after the 2fa authentication my solution was use other terminal outside vscode and this prompted to enter the user name and password