# Kubernetes private registry (gitlab) image pulling on different nodes

Tags: docker, kubernetes, gitlab, gitlab-ci, kubernetes-helm

I have a Kubernetes cluster with 2 nodes. Now when I deploy with Gitlab CI to the cluster it will deploy an application normally.

But when I'll add a cronjob service which uses the same image as the application to the charts that are being used by the Gitlab CI (helm charts). it runs on the node where the application itself is also being deployed, but not on the other node.

Error:

```
Failed to pull image "gitlab.example.nl:4567/v2/namespace/project/manifests/0998034a-ae44-457e-bb5e-3d3304a2fc54": rpc error: code = Unknown desc = Error response from daemon: Get https://gitlab.example.nl:4567/v2/namespace/project/manifests/0998034a-ae44-457e-bb5e-3d3304a2fc54: unauthorized: HTTP Basic: Access denied
```

<sub><sup>Changed urls for not exposing company</sup></sub>

Example:

```
Node1:
Does not run cronjob, because it cannot pull the image.

Node2:
Runs application normally
Runs cronjobs normally
```

Both the deployment and the cronjob charts do have the `ImagePullSecrets` property, I have set the token validity time to 15 minutes

Example of k8s dashboard
[image: k8s image]

Cronjob.yaml (helm chart)

```
apiVersion: batch/v1beta1
kind: CronJob
metadata:
  name: {{ template "trackableappname" . }}-cron
spec:
  schedule: "*/1 * * * *"
  jobTemplate:
    spec:
      template:
        spec:
          imagePullSecrets:
{{ toYaml .Values.image_fpm.secrets | indent 12 }}
          volumes:
            - name: appdir
              emptyDir: {}
            {{- if .Values.storage.enabled }}
            - name: cron-{{ .Values.storage.name }}-pv-storage
              persistentVolumeClaim:
                claimName: {{ .Values.storage.name }}-pv-claim
            {{- end }}
            - name: secrets
              secret:
                secretName: environment-file
          containers:
            - name: fpm-{{ .Chart.Name }}-cronjob
              image: "{{ .Values.image_fpm.repository }}:{{ .Values.image_fpm.tag }}"
              imagePullPolicy: {{ .Values.image_fpm.pullPolicy }}
              command: ["/bin/sh"]
              args: ["-c", "{{ .Values.application.cronCommand }}"]
              volumeMounts:
              - name: appdir
                mountPath: /var/www/html
              {{- if .Values.storage.enabled }}
              - name: cron-{{ .Values.storage.name }}-pv-storage
                mountPath: /var/www/html/storage
              {{- end }}
              - name: secrets
                mountPath: /var/secrets
              {{- if .Values.application.secretName }}
              envFrom:
              - secretRef:
                  name: {{ .Values.application.secretName }}
              {{- end }}
              env:
                - name: "APP_DEBUG"
                  value: "false"
                - name: ENVIRONMENT_FILE
                  valueFrom:
                    secretKeyRef:
                      name: environment-file
                      key: ENVIRONMENT_FILE
          initContainers:
            - name: copy-{{ .Chart.Name }}-cronjob
              image: "{{ .Values.image_workspace.repository }}:{{ .Values.image_workspace.tag }}"
              command: ["/bin/sh"]
              args: ["-c", "{{ .Values.application.initCommand }}"]
              env:
                - name: ENVIRONMENT_FILE
                  valueFrom:
                    secretKeyRef:
                      name: environment-file
                      key: ENVIRONMENT_FILE
              volumeMounts:
                - name: appdir
                  mountPath: /var/www/application
              imagePullPolicy: {{ .Values.image_fpm.pullPolicy }}
          restartPolicy: OnFailure
```

Comment: Maybe node1's outbound traffic is restricted?

Comment: No, Both the nodes are the same anders dont have restrictions tot the registry

Comment: Can you post the describe log on the failed job?

Comment: can you share the cronjob yaml?

Comment: @cookiedough i have runned `kubectl decribe pods POD` but i didn't get any extra information

Comment: @Amityo I have added the cronjob.yaml!

Comment: Are you still experiencing this issue?

Comment: Yes, i have Made a workaround by using the crontab in a container, but i stil need to fix iT

Comment: @MrChrissss I think this is GiLlab related. I was able to find this [case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17074941/git-failed-to-erase-credential-element-not-found)

Comment: @Crou I will try to disable the 2fa and check if it works