# GitHub, HTTPS and Mac application

Tags: macos, git, github

I know SSH in GitHub causes no problem (no username/password to type everytime i.e.), but I need to use HTTPS for a repo of mine.

Now, I `git init`ed  the repo, I committed, I did a `git remote add origin https://github.com/user/repo.git` *as suggested by GitHub*.

I was about to do a `git push -u origin master`: first it promped me for username and password, and then answered with:

```
remote: Anonymous access to user/repo.git denied.
fatal: Authentication failed for 'https://github.com/user/repo.git/'
```

I'm 300% sure I typed the right password (and I tried again a couple times anyway).
I googled here and there, and then I tried my last chance: installing the GitHub app for Mac.
I entered my credentials, entered the 2-factor auth code they sent me, and tried to push again: this time it worked.

Why? What did the GitHub app do behind the scenes? Has it something to do with the 2-factor auth?

Anyway, I would be able to not download the app on every machine I setup, maybe by automating this process with some script.

Comment: Have you set-up `credential-osxkeychain` as per the instructions on the github site? https://help.github.com/articles/set-up-git#platform-mac

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Your GitHub password won't work if you have activated the two-factor authentication.

You need to generate a Personal Access Token, as I explain in "[Configure Git clients, like GitHub for Windows, to not ask for authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18607931/6309)".

That long (40 characters) password will work as your GitHub password *without* requiring a second authentication.

The difference between a PAT (Personnal Access token) and your Github password account:

- It doesn't required the second step, but:
- it is more complex than a simple password (not meant to be remembered)
- you can generate as many as you want (one for each different computer from which you access GitHub, for instance)
- you can revoke it at any time (easier than having to change your GitHub password)

And you can encrypt your GitHub credential in a `.netrc.gpg` file, as I illustrate in "[Is there a way to skip password typing when using https:// github](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18362082/6309)".
I find that far superior to a memory-caching mechanism (like credential-osxkeychain), since you don't have to type your GitHub (long and complex token) password at each session.
You only type the passphrase of your gpg key, for that GitHub login/token credential, **or for any other credential that you have encrypted in your  `~/.netrc.gpg` file**.