# Getting the following error while doing pull and push operations (git-upload-pack not permitted on )

Tags: git, eclipse, egit

I am facing git config issues for last couple of days before that i done lot of commits and pull but this time getting this error.

```
git-upload-pack not permitted on
```

[image: error]

Please help me to get this issue resolved.

Comment: Note that github no longer support https for write access, you have to use ssh - see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68802292/2670892)

Comment: @greg-449 It does support it if you use as password a token. I push using https all the time.

Comment: @VonC So what changed on August 13th? I read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68802292/2670892) as saying that doesn't work anymore.

Comment: Did changing the java client work?

Comment: @VonC - In future can I change password as per my wish? or always I need to use the same access token for every time?

Comment: @Jay I have edited my answer to address your last comment/question. Let me known if this is clear enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in [this thread](https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/1104150/):

> EGit supports two different HTTP clients: by default it uses the Apache libraries, but it can also use the JDK built-in HTTP client
>
> I had exactly the same issue with eclipse 2020-12.
> In `Preferences->Git` I changed "`Http Client`" to "`Java built-in HTTP`" and the issue is resolved.

As noted in the comments, you need to use a [PAT (Personal Access token)](https://docs.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/keeping-your-account-and-data-secure/creating-a-personal-access-token) as password now.

As I [explain here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19223896/6309), you can then change your GitHub password as many time as you want.
Your token (unless it has an expiration date, which, by default, is 7 days, but can be changed at creation) will remain valid.

Conversely, you can revoke a token, without having to change your main password.

Comment: Where can i find Preferences->Git  ->HttpClient? I have tried to find.. can you share a snapshot?

Comment: @beingshuchi Maybe the preferences have changed, or they depend on a plugin (JGit/Egit) that you might not have. In any case, you can just type HTTP Client in the preference search field, and it will show you every occurrence of that setting.

Answer (score 0):

@greg-449 It does support it if you use as password a token. I push using https all the time.

Hi Greg and VonC,

The above method worked for me. I have generated a token key in git and i used that as a my password. now i can do push and pull operations.

Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: Great. I have completed my answer with a reference to PAT.