# Problems with cloning a git repository to new computer

Tags: github, cloning

This might be trivial, but it has caused me a ton of headaches over the last few days.
Recently i have tried to clone my git repos onto my new computer, but up until now, with no succes.
After typing "git clone " followed by the respective git URL, my comand line is asking for my Username and passwort. Even though i provide both correctly, i get the following error:

[image]

I do not have 2FA enabled, and as i understand it, the access token is only required in the case of enabled 2FA.

Does anyone have any idea what i am doing wrong?

Comment: Access token *was* only required if you had 2FA enabled. Now it is required for all. See the provided link. https://github.blog/2020-12-15-token-authentication-requirements-for-git-operations/ Perhaps on your old machine you were using ssh keys?

Comment: Note that while this particular kind of access token is specific to GitHub, it seems that most Git hosting services are moving in the same direction here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A token is not jsut required for 2FA.

It is [now (since mid 2021)](https://github.blog/2020-12-15-token-authentication-requirements-for-git-operations/) required for any web operation with authentication, using said token as a password.

You need to [create a PAT (Personal Access Token)](https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/keeping-your-account-and-data-secure/creating-a-personal-access-token), with [scope '`repo`'](https://docs.github.com/en/developers/apps/building-oauth-apps/scopes-for-oauth-apps#available-scopes).

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. Could you elaborate on that a little more? Is it enough if i just create the token in github and than use it as my "passwort"?

Comment: @YanKlinkenick Yes, that is the idea. On the difference between a token and a regular account password, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19223896/6309).