# Github - Fatal Authentication Failed - Yet I can still connect?

Tags: github, git-bash

My github isn't connecting.  I've tried two different computers and I'm getting the same error so clearly I'm doing something wrong.  When I run `git push` I get prompted for my username / password as expected.  Type them in, and yes I'm typing them correctly.  Then it says:

```
fatal: Authentication failed
```

However when I type `ssh -T git@github.com` it prompts me for my passphrase and after entering that, it welcomes me to github.  I've tried to add the SSH key again and all it says is this SSH key is already on the account.  Someone let me know what I'm missing?

When I try to login it shows:

`Password for http://(UserName)@www.github.com:`

Is that correct?

More Information: Here's the output of ssh-vT git@github.com:

```
$ ssh-add -l
Could not open a connection to your authentication agent.
```

_

```
$ ssh -vT git@github.com
OpenSSH_4.6p1, OpenSSL 0.9.8e 23 Feb 2007
debug1: Connecting to github.com [192.30.252.129] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /l/.ssh/identity type -1
debug1: identity file /l/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: identity file /l/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_5.9p1 Debia
n-5ubuntu1+github5
debug1: match: OpenSSH_5.9p1 Debian-5ubuntu1+github5 pat OpenSSH*
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_4.6
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-cbc hmac-md5 none
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-cbc hmac-md5 none
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REQUEST(1024<1024<8192) sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_GROUP
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_INIT sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REPLY
debug1: Host 'github.com' is known and matches the RSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /l/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug1: ssh_rsa_verify: signature correct
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /l/.ssh/identity
debug1: Offering public key: /l/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Server accepts key: pkalg ssh-rsa blen 277
debug1: read PEM private key done: type RSA
debug1: Authentication succeeded (publickey).
debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug1: Remote: Forced command.
debug1: Remote: Port forwarding disabled.
debug1: Remote: X11 forwarding disabled.
debug1: Remote: Agent forwarding disabled.
debug1: Remote: Pty allocation disabled.
debug1: Remote: Forced command.
debug1: Remote: Port forwarding disabled.
debug1: Remote: X11 forwarding disabled.
debug1: Remote: Agent forwarding disabled.
debug1: Remote: Pty allocation disabled.
debug1: client_input_channel_req: channel 0 rtype exit-status reply 0
Hi ____! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell ac
cess.
debug1: channel 0: free: client-session, nchannels 1
debug1: Transferred: stdin 0, stdout 0, stderr 0 bytes in 0.1 seconds
debug1: Bytes per second: stdin 0.0, stdout 0.0, stderr 0.0
debug1: Exit status 1
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try instead of linking to github through http go through ssh. do `git remote set-url origin <ssh url>` and then try doing `git push`

The ssh url should be something like `git@github.com...`

Answer (score 3):

You can try ...

1 Edit your remote repository

```
git remote set-url origin your-remote-repository-ssh-url
```

2 Push your code.

```
git push origin ...
```

Where will you find your ssh-url?

1 In your repositories page

[image]

2 Click ssh link and copy your ssh-url

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you have this problem, you have basically two solutions as your options:

1. If you insist on using HTTPS to connect to Github, you'll need to get a Personal Access Token from your account on Github instead of your password.
2. You'll need to switch to SSH and use that to login.

For both options, check out [this Stack Overflow question and its excellent first answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17659206/git-push-results-in-authentication-failed) for how to go about implementing them.