# Git remote: Repository not found for https, after setting up for another account with ssh

Tags: git, github

I'm using `https` for my work git **private** repo. Yesterday I followed [this](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/quick-tip-how-to-work-with-github-and-multiple-accounts--net-22574) along with git instructions to set up for my personal account on the same machine with ssh. It worked fine, but today I'm trying to `pull` from work repo and getting following:

```
remote: Repository not found.
fatal: repository 'https://github.com/Divorcemate/cloud2016.git/' not found
```

My coworkers have to problem pulling.
I don't see any change when  `git config --list` which could have caused this.
As well I tried removing the origin from `config` file and adding with `git remote add origin` and it didn't help.

Comment: Is that the precise URL that the Github UI provided you?

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth, yep

Answer (score 0):

When I look at [your Github user page](https://github.com/Divorcemate?tab=repositories) it says:

```
Divorcemate doesn’t have any public repositories yet.
```

Are you sure that the repository `cloud2016` is public? HTTPS is unauthenticated/anonymous on Github. Didn't you perhaps have a `git@github.com/Divorcemate/cloud2016.git` before this happened in your remote?

Comment: The repo is private. As well I definitely didn't change the config file, so it should be as it was prior to any change.

Comment: Did you look at how authentication is done for HTTPS access? There is another question about it here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21027728/6769270 I don't have private repos and cannot really verify it.