# Git clone command line https authorization error

Tags: git, authentication, github

I have installed the git command line. 
Every time I try to clone a repo I get an authentication error.

fatal: Authentication failed for ....

It works on my mac but not on my windows laptop. Does anyone have an idea?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Git push results in "Authentication Failed"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17659206/git-push-results-in-authentication-failed)

Comment: doenst look like its the same issue because I could not even clone it.

Comment: What are you trying to clone? Does it require authentication? Have you provided the correct credentials?

Comment: solved -> http://stackoverflow.com/a/43039662/7825397

Answer (score 1):

you can use code in command line

```
git clone https://username@example.com/.../project_name.git
```

or

```
git clone https://username:password@example.com/.../project_name.git
```

Answer (score 0):

Should save git auth username and password on windows credential manager
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I have got same error. Go to control panel -> User Account --> Credential Manager
and edit git credentials.

[image]