# Error in login with git and github

Tags: git, github

I am trying go up a project HTML5 to github from terminal linux/ubuntu and its give that ? and the user and password is correct I am login with that user and password, anyone know but I have this error ? I m confused.

Message Error :

```
git push -u origin master
Username for 'https://github.com': gilbertoquinteroA
Password for 'https://gilbertoquinteroA@github.com': 
remote: Invalid username or password.
fatal: Authentication failed for 'https://github.com/gilbertoquinteroA/Theme-Basico-without-HTML5-and-CSS3.git/'
```

Comment: May be you could find something at https://stackoverflow.com/q/17659206/7976758 or https://stackoverflow.com/q/7438313/7976758

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, check if your password has a special character, as you might have to [percent encode it](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding#Character_data).

Second, check if your account [has 2FA activated](https://help.github.com/articles/securing-your-account-with-two-factor-authentication-2fa/): you would need to use a [PTA (Personal Token Access)](https://help.github.com/articles/creating-a-personal-access-token-for-the-command-line/) as a password.