# GitBucket: Cannot access remotely

Tags: git, git-remote, gitbucket

I want to push a project to a remote repository But somehow I get an error

> Git: fatal: Authentication failed for 'https://......'

This error was previously handled by cloning a new remote repository and copying the settings
But this time I can't even clone

[So this is the question I referred to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17659206/git-push-results-in-authentication-failed)

I can't think of anything more than this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you delete the Windows credentials and re-register, it went well