# Authentication issue while fetching from fork branch in git

Tags: git, bitbucket, git-fetch

I am trying to fetch from my colleagues fork using the following command:

```
git remote add fellow https://<servername>/~nsarkr/<application>.git
```

Next I try to fetch the branches:

```
git fetch fellow
```

I get the following error:

```
fatal: Authentication failed for 'https://<servername>/~nsarkr/<application>.git'
```

But I'm not sure what can authenticate me.
I am aware that my colleague may create personal tokens and can share it with me, but how would I use that?
I need to use the `fetch` command. I don't want to clone the repo again, since that would clutter my workspace.

The following article explains about cloning the repo using personal tokens.

https://help.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/creating-a-personal-access-token-for-the-command-line

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: This depends on the type of server being used for the remote. Perhaps you've stored credentials for this remote before that have now expired? https://stackoverflow.com/a/50105930/283078