# Can't push to GitHub after enabling two factor auth

Tags: github, ssh

I've been pushing my repos just fine, then enabled two factor authentication and can no longer push.

I created an SSH key and added it to my GitHub account, then created a config file in `~/.ssh/config` and added the following.

```
Host *
  AddKeysToAgent yes
  UseKeychain yes
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa

Host github.com
    HostName github.com
    User [myusername]
    IdentitiesOnly yes
```

Yet when I push a repo it's asking for my GitHub username and password, and after entering them then tells me I don't have authorization.

```
remote: Invalid username or password.
```

I even tried using my auth backup code for the password, but no good.

Since I'm on macOS Catalina I tried

```
eval "$(ssh-agent -s)"
ssh-add -l -E md5
```

Which resulted in the `"This agent has no identities"` message. So of course I did the following

```
ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

And tried it again and it's still the same. I'm basically stuck in a loop of nothing working and don't know what to do!

Comment: Just to confirm, your `git remote -v` does not have a HTTPS URL, right?

Comment: It actually does. `https://github.com/myusername/myrepo.git (push)`

Comment: You need to change that for using SSH. See [this](https://help.github.com/en/github/using-git/changing-a-remotes-url#switching-remote-urls-from-https-to-ssh).

Comment: Thank you! Please put that as an answer so I can give you credit.

Comment: Good to know it worked. However similar questions have been asked several times, so perhaps it is better to close as a duplicate. You could accept the duplicate target instead.

Comment: Yep, that did it. I spent over an hour trying to find a solution; I guess I just wasn't asking the question properly. Thanks again!

Comment: This should provide an easier method: https://stackoverflow.com/a/75124900/18588998