# List git credentials from credential helper

Tags: git, git-config, git-credential-manager

Seems like a simple problem but I can't find a solution, in my *git config credentials* stored
in the cache(username and personal access token) the `git config --list` returns the credential info like this

```
credential.helper=cache
```

Is it possible to see the credentials from the cache, I tried the following three locations

1. (repository_home) `/.git/config` - there is no info about the *username* and *password*
2. `~/.gitconfig` -  file not found in the repo folder

Comment: Do you have this file `~/.git-credentials` ?

Comment: No such file or dir

Comment: Ahh you are using cache method. `cache` Cache credentials in memory for a short period of time. If you are looking towards storing on disk you should use `store` method instead.

Comment: Yes memory I don't want to change I just want to see the creds

Answer (score 18):

From [git-credential](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-credential) `git credential fill` could be helpful here, you need to input host and protocol details to get username and password.

```
$ git credential fill
protocol=https
host=example.com
```

Output:

```
protocol=https
host=example.com
username=bob
password=secret
```

Answer (score 8):

It is possible for you to query a particular set of credentials from the credential helper, but there isn't a part of the credential helper protocol that allows you to query all credentials.  In general, this is hard, because a credential helper can respond to all credentials that match a pattern, such as `https://*.example.org` or `https://github.com/bk2204/*`, and that pattern need not match any simple pattern that can be expressed (for example, the helper could have intimate knowledge about which repositories a user has access to based on LDAP).

For the `cache` credential helper, there isn't a way to enumerate those credentials.

If you want to look up the credentials for a particular URL, the easiest way to do that is like this:

```
echo url=https://github.com/git/git.git | git credential fill
```

That will print the credentials that any credential helper knows about.  You can see more about the protocol in the `gitcredentials(7)` man page.

Answer (score 0):

The Input/output format for [git credential is documented here](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-credential#IOFMT), and can be used with `echo` (one attribute) or `printf` (multiple attributes)

```
echo url=https://github.com/git/git.git | git credential fill
# or
printf "protocol=https\nhost=github.com"  | git credential fill
```

And that will work with any registered credential helper, whose list has been extended with Git 2.42 (Q3 2023):

See [commit 4c9cb51](https://github.com/git/git/commit/4c9cb51fe7beafc1033ec33e7f9d431c04d8b278) (08 Jul 2023) by [M Hickford (`hickford`)](https://github.com/hickford).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit d6e6722](https://github.com/git/git/commit/d6e67222c103783616912c26c9906b8167c39ab8), 18 Jul 2023)</sup>

> ### [`doc`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/4c9cb51fe7beafc1033ec33e7f9d431c04d8b278): gitcredentials: link to helper list
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: M Hickford</sup>

> Link to community list of credential helpers.
> This is useful information for users.
>
> Describe how OAuth credential helpers work.
> OAuth is a user-friendly alternative to personal access tokens and SSH keys.
> Reduced setup cost makes it easier for users to contribute to projects across multiple forges.

`gitcredentials` now includes in its [man page](https://github.com/git/git/blob/4c9cb51fe7beafc1033ec33e7f9d431c04d8b278/Documentation/gitcredentials.txt#L107-L117):

> ### Available helpers
>
> The community maintains a comprehensive list of Git credential helpers at
> https://git-scm.com/doc/credential-helpers.
>
> ### OAuth
>
> An alternative to inputting passwords or personal access tokens is to use an
> OAuth credential helper. Initial authentication opens a browser window to the
> host. Subsequent authentication happens in the background. Many popular Git
> hosts support OAuth.