# Git Authentication Failed when I made push or pull (Only throught console)

Tags: git, github, terminal

I get this error when I want to do any operation throught Android Studio Console:

```
fatal: Authentication failed for (url github repository)
```

But if I use an git interfaz (in my case I am using Android Studio and Github Desktop) and I make `pull` or `push`, works fine, no errors. This error only happens when I use any console (like Visual Studio Console) in my project.

I had cloned again the repository and it didn't work...

This error appeared when I had changed in my computer its HDD to SSD, then I copied again my project folder to my SSD, opened it in Android Studio and the error appeared, but only throught console.

I have tried the 3 first solutions in this post but not worked for me: [Git push results in "Authentication Failed"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17659206/git-push-results-in-authentication-failed)

Someone has idea to solve this?

Comment: Have you tried updating your credentials in the [credential manager](https://cmatskas.com/how-to-update-your-git-credentials-on-windows/)?

Comment: @JeffGruenbaum yes man, I had tried that, but not worked. Moreover I have delete the git credentials and reenter then and also didn't work

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Finally I got the solution, only we need to put this command in the terminal:

```
git credential-manager uninstall
```

And then, when we make `pull` or `push` will be requested our credentials, and that's all

Comment: I am getting error: `git: 'credential-manager' is not a git command. See 'git --help'.`

Answer (score 0):

Go to > `Control Panel` > `User Accounts` > `Credential Manager` > `Windows Credentials` and remove all *generic credentials* involving **Git**. With this, you are resetting all the credentials. After resetting, when you `git clone` your repository again, you will be newly and the securely asked your for username and password instead of *Authentication Error* and will write the new git-credentials to your Credential Manager for further authentication.

Comment: I followed your steps but also didn't works it. When I cloned the repository I put my credentials and the operation was successful, and I can make push and pull throught Android Studio Interface as I could make before, but throught its console shows me the same error