# Git push rejected due to authentication

Tags: git, github

I'm using GitHub for pushing my code.
But facing issues while using git push due authentication problem.

> git push

Please help with solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple google search will help, you need to check whether you have right set of credentials, sometimes your credentials might not be updated.

For more info you can refer to this link
[Git push results in "Authentication Failed"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17659206/git-push-results-in-authentication-failed)

Comment: Please add the relevant details of the link to your answers. Links can become outdated