# git --- How to schedule `git push` on linux?

Tags: linux, git, scheduler, git-push

I think the title describes my problem well: I want to schedule `git push`. To be more specific, I'd like to know how I can either

- tell `git` to make push at a specified time
- tell OS to execute `git push` at a specified time without re-authentication 
  (preferably, in such a way that the other attempts to `push` shall require authentication.).

I'm on linux (Ubuntu 13.04) and thus scripting with bash will be fine.

Comment: Read up on *“cron jobs”*.

Comment: @poke Thanks, using cron and ssh connection (am I right?) seems to do the job.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is nothing in git which includes:

- scheduling (this is provided by [Ubuntu with cron jobs](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CronHowto))
- authentication: it depends on the kind of listener (https, ssh, git, ...) you have on the remote side.

Depending on your remote url, you can, for instance:

- use a dedicate public/private ssh key.
- use encrypted credentials (username/password) with https url (as in "[Configure Git clients, like GitHub for Windows, to not ask for authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18607931/6309)")

Answer (score 1):

you can schedule such jobs using `cron`.

```
00 07 * * * git push
```

will run `git push` command everyday at 7 AM.