# Clone a private repo of github with username and password

Tags: git, authentication, github, git-clone, private-repository

I have configured Account A on my system with Global configurations and I can clone all my repos from there.

Now I don't want to change the configuration and I want to clone and do all operations of account B with my username and password. How can I do this?

I have tried:

```
git clone username:passwordgit@github.com:*****/******.git
```

But with no success.

Answer (score 54):

You can try with the complete https url:

```
git clone https://username:<token>@github.com/*****/******.git
```

If you omit the `https://` part (and use '`:`' instead of '/'), it would be interpreted like an ssh url.

The GitHub help page "[Which remote URL should I use?](https://help.github.com/articles/which-remote-url-should-i-use)" confirms an https url can access private repos.

Note: I wouldn't put the token directly in the url, but [use a credential manager to get the right password for the right user](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18607931/6309).

```
git clone https://username@github.com/*****/******.git
```

---

Reminder: [since Aug. 2021](https://github.blog/2020-12-15-token-authentication-requirements-for-git-operations/) Token (or SSH key) authentication are required for all authenticated Git operations for GitHub.
Here, the token is a [**PAT (Personal Access Token)**](https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/keeping-your-account-and-data-secure/creating-a-personal-access-token).

Comment: when two-factor authentication is enabled, you would need to generate a temporary access token https://help.github.com/articles/which-remote-url-should-i-use/#when-2fa-is-enabled

Comment: @mission.liao I agree. I describe PAT (Personal Access Token) in http://stackoverflow.com/a/18607931/6309

Comment: @alhelal that should follow the same principle, so yes, it should work with Bitbucket as well.

Answer (score 17):

Just to make the syntax a bit clearer, to clone a private repository use:

```
git clone https://[insert username]:[insert password]@github.com/[insert organisation name]/[insert repo name].git
```

or

```
git clone https://[insert username]@github.com/[insert organisation name]/[insert repo name].git
```

Example:

```
git clone https://myusername:mypassword@github.com/myorgname/myreponame.git
```