# Clonning repository error using sourcetree

Tags: github, repository, clone, atlassian-sourcetree

I have the next error from sourcetree when i try to clone a repository (private):[image]

```
Cloning into 'C:\Users\xxxxxxx\Documents\Tutoriales'...
remote: Repository not found.
```

This error is happening since four days ago.
The repository exist but i don't understand whta happens, i try using shell also and i have the same error.

Comment: the repository ... exist !

Answer (score 0):

The error is saying that the repository doesn't exist. It looks like there is a spelling mistake. Should it be

> tutorials.git

The project is also private, will it allow you to even see it if this is its visabality. Try making it public just to test.

Comment: It just happens with private repositories, **with a public repository SourceTree can clone the repo to local, without problem.** what is wrong?
Thanks

Comment: if its private you may need to get access for it, alternatively have you tried creating a SSH key and using the ssh link to clone it. There are some other links on stackoverflow http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22755268/clone-a-private-repo-of-github-with-username-and-password

Comment: The solution was. delete credential from windows.