# Using Http to push into github project

Tags: git, http, github, ssh

Question.
To push my files into github, do I need to setup ssh key or can I use http?
If so, I'm curious of how to do it through http?

Comment: Of course you can use https. What problems do you face with it? Make sure you have write access to the repo before push.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find all the details in "[Which remote URL should I use?](https://help.github.com/articles/which-remote-url-should-i-use)"

An https url would use as your credentials your GitHub account username and password.

Note that if you have [two-factor authentication](https://help.github.com/articles/about-two-factor-authentication) enabled, you must create a [personal access token](https://help.github.com/articles/creating-an-access-token-for-command-line-use) to use instead of your GitHub password.
I explain more at "[Configure Git clients, like GitHub for Windows, to not ask for authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18607931/6309)"