# Github EGit and Netbeans git: push not working

Tags: eclipse, git, netbeans, github, push

I had a repository that I have been updating for a few months with perfect ease from within Eclipse & Netbeans. Then one day, it asked me for my password again. I kept putting in my password, but it still didn't work. I went into my github account, pressed the security and revoked all of the current logins. There was one that I didn't approve of. It was from Miami. In the security history, I saw a login from this IP: 199.111.189.110. I changed my password and tried on Netbeans, but it didn't work. Please help.

**UPDATE:** I am using 2-factor auth and an https url

Here is my [repo](https://github.com/theTechnoKid/DataDude).

Comment: Did you use an https or ssh url for your remote repo 'origin' in your local repo? Did you activated 2FA? (https://help.github.com/articles/about-two-factor-authentication/)

Comment: @VonC I have 2FA & an https url

Comment: Then you must use a token access,  which might have been compromised or revoked (the regular GitHub password account doesn't work with 2fa)

Comment: @VonC How do I use token access?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If [2FA is activated](https://help.github.com/articles/about-two-factor-authentication/), then, as I described in "[Configure Git clients, like GitHub for Windows, to not ask for authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18607931/6309)", one need to use a 
Personal Access Token (PAT), listed in the [`Applications` section of one's GitHub Account](https://github.com/settings/applications).

A token can be used as a password when 2FA is set, while the regular GitHub account password wouldn't work.

Comment: I made a _netrc file. When I am pushing, do I have to put in the token that github made for the password?

Comment: It worked! I saw your previous answer but didn't have time to try it!