# Enabling two-factor auth on GitHub: Can I still push/pull some repos without access tokens?

Tags: git, github, two-factor-authentication

For a new job, the company asked me to enable two-factor authentication on my GitHub account. So then I learned that I now I can't push and pull like before (I had set `credential.helper` to `osxkeychain`) but instead need access tokens.
Using my token for a password works, but can I avoid having to type it in every time? Or can I at least go back to the old ways for my personal non-company repos?
How do professional devs usually handle this?

Comment: How about using SSH keys for authentication? This should "trump" two factor authentication (if you mean the web login two factor authentication thing)

Comment: @rubenvb This appears to work. Care to make it an answer for anyone else running into this?

Comment: I do use a PAT for 2FA on GitHub. but with an encrypted netrc: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18607931/6309, and its associated netrc credential helper: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18362082/6309

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to mess with passwords and/or access tokens, [set up an SSH key](https://help.github.com/articles/adding-a-new-ssh-key-to-your-github-account/) so that git will authenticate itself with that. Guard the key with your life!